# How to connect two separate paths in sketch app?

Tags: sketch-app, pathfinder

I want to connect the round shaped open path with the second open path. No idea how to do this in Sketch App. I've done it in Illustrator a tonne of times.[image: two open paths that I'd like to make into one]

Answer (score 12):

One way to go is to select your paths, go to Layer -> Paths -> Join

[image: Path]

Comment: And if you don't want the end-node of the right-hand side path to "jump", do this: 1) insert a new dummy end-node to the right hand side path 2) perform the join; the dummy node will jump/combine with the node from the right-hand side path 3) delete the dummy node. The end result is a straight-line path between the two original path end-nodes.